# Opening save ,saveas dialog from ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

When I Use

window.location = '<%= Url.Action("DownloadFile", "Home") %>?fileId=id,

I am getting the contents in a diffrent screen altogether

But how to open it as a popup like open,save,save as dialog box?

I am hitting a ActionResult DownloadFile() 
which returns a File object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the third argument of the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470835.aspx) method to specify a filename. This will have as an effect to set the `Content-Disposition` HTTP response header to `attachment` popping a Save As dialog when the user navigates to this action:

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string fileId)
{
    byte[] file = ...
    // TODO: adjust the MIME type and filename extension to your case accordingly
    return File(file, "text/plain", "foo.txt");
}
```

Then:

```
var id = '1234';
window.location.href = '<%= Url.Action("DownloadFile", "Home") %>?fileId=' + id;
```

will work just fine.